# User profile apps view title contains "...Users.Show.AppsModel"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stackapps

On the user profile apps page (located at `http://stackoverflow.com/users/apps/{userId}`) the `<title>` element contains the following content:

```
Applications used by StackOverflow.Views.Users.Show.AppsModel - Stack Overflow
```

*Looks to me like somebody forgot a member property accessor somewhere along the way.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: This is now fixed. Thank you!